# Is There Any Difference Between SqlConnection.CreateCommand and new SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In .Net, is there any functional difference between creating a new `SqlCommand` object and attaching a `SqlConnection` to it and calling `CreateCommand()` on an existing `SqlConnection` object?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, they are the same thing.

I disassembled `SqlConnection.CreateCommand` and found this:

```
public SqlCommand CreateCommand()
{
        return new SqlCommand(null, this);
}
```

which proves that they really are the same thing.

Answer (score 13):

They do the same thing. The rationale behind `SqlConnection.CreateCommand` is to implement the factory pattern.

Answer (score 10):

Functionally they are exactly the same.

However, `SqlConnection.CreateCommand()` lets you be more agnostic about what type of DB you are using. For example instead of passing a `SqlConnection` instance around you could pass it around as a `DbConnection` which would yield a `DbCommand`.

Answer (score 3):

This may go without saying, but just to be complete, there is one difference.  If you create a SqlCommand, you can pass in the CommandText as a parameter.  If you let the SqlConnection CreateCommand, there is no provision for supplying the CommandText.  Since you can just set the SqlCommand's CommandText property, the distinction is pretty slim, but it does exist.

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select @@version";
```

or

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select @@version", db);
```