# C# and MySQL Command - two different syles?

Tags: c#, mysql

So, after many hours of learning MySQL and trying to get my code to work.  I have found at least two different ways to set up the SQL Command.  From that, I have, hopefully, a general question in MySQL using C#.

What is the difference between these two Commands:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

and

```
MySqlCommand cmd; 
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Is one preferred over the other?

I've ran both and both seem to work fine inserting data in my db table.  I don't know if it'll help answer it, but here's my code:

```
 public static void AddSong(Songs s)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn;
        string myConnectionString;

        myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
            "pwd=mysql;database=MySQL_TestDB;";

        conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        string query = "INSERT INTO Songs (Title, Artist) VALUES (" +
                    "@Title, " +
                    "@Artist)";

        /*
        MySqlCommand cmd; 
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        */

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", s.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", s.Artist);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();   
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the same question as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302855/is-there-any-difference-between-sqlconnection-createcommand-and-new-sqlcommand

Comment: @Terminus, Wow, I really spent nearly 20 minutes searching for an answer.  I just didn't know what to type in I guess.  Thanks!

Comment: I googled `c# difference between sql command and createcommand` first result for me. A couple of interesting looking results after though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, AFAIK they both are same and does the same thing. `conn.CreateCommand()` actually returns a new `MySqlCommand` instance.

As the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) clearly says

> Creates and returns a SqlCommand object associated with the
>   SqlConnection.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul and @Termininus!

Comment: Though the linked documentation is for `SqlCommand` but it will be same behavior for `MySqlCommand` class as well.

Comment: I'm wondering if that was done on purpose?  I've been using the SqlCommand using MS SQL Server and just started using MySQL.  I had to change a few things like you mentioned `MySqlCommand`, and a funky thing with the connection string (that took forever by the way).  Thanks again.

Comment: @KerryWhite, `MySqlCommand` class is provided by MySQL connecter (driver for C#) but underlying they follow the same design/architecture. So would be same across all different RDBMS drivers.